# Why is the next field explicitly set to null?

Tags: c, pointers

I was watching this [Computerphile Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5NszbIerYc). In the description, [this code](http://www.eprg.org/computerphile/tradlink.c) was posted.

In the code provided,

```
THING *newelement(char *text)
{
    THING *newp;
    newp = (THING *) malloc (sizeof(THING));
    newp->item = (char *)malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
        strcpy(newp->item, text);
        newp -> next = NULL;
    return newp;
}
```

they had this method. In this method, there is a line `newp -> next = NULL`. Why do we have to explicitly set the next field equal to null.

I thought about this as follows. The bottom line is that we are returning a pointer to this struct to the user. The user knows that they have provided the method with text but no next reference. *Regardless* of whether or not we set the next reference to null, if the user chooses to dereference the next field, either a segfault will happen or undefined behavior will occur which are both undesirable.

Comment: Is it about singly-linked lists?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes

Comment: Just to be tidy. Dereferencing the `NULL` pointer is predictable, whereas left indeterminate might misbehave but not crash.

Comment: Do you have any function going through all of the list? E.g. one to output all values? Show that and you will probably find a reason for the NULL.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks! That's another great reason I didn't think of. Reminds me of how strlen(dest, src) requires the null terminator 0.

Comment: Unrelated comment: change to `newp = malloc (sizeof(THING));`, you don't need casting for `malloc` in C.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Dosen't malloc return a void pointer?

Comment: Yes it does, but you don't need cast when assigning `void` pointer to another pointer type. In c++ it does need that cast, but you wouldn't use `malloc` in c++. Try to avoid using cast unless you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the user chooses to dereference the next field...

If the user is able to *check* whether the `next` field is invalid, they probably won't dereference it because they supposedly know that dereferencing an invalid pointer is "bad" (can cause a segfault or read garbage data). Thus, if you set `next` to `NULL`, you enable the user to check whether the field is valid or not.

If you leave it uninitialized (or rather, initialized with whatever garbage data `malloc` provided), the user will be left assuming that the pointer is valid, because you can't guarantee that it'll be `NULL`.

Comment: So you mean like if (struct->next == NULL). If we aren't explicit in our implementation, then the user can't do the following and might read garbage data?

Comment: @NeelSandell, yep, any pointer that's not `NULL` may potentially point to valid data.  So, there's no obvious reason not to dereference it. A `NULL` pointer definitely (unless you're doing low-level bare-metal stuff) doesn't point to valid data - that's the whole point. So the user of your function will check for `NULL` (indeed, similar to the `\0` terminator for strings) to see whether they reached the end of the list.